# Proof of $x = y \leftrightarrow x \in \{y\}$

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic

Considering x and y are variables, to prove $x \in \{y\} \rightarrow x = y$, we have to assume the uniqueness of the element in $\{y\}$, which means $\forall z[z \in \{y\} \rightarrow z = y]$, and then apply universal instantiation. But I can't relate existence (if it is the case) to the proof of $x = y \rightarrow x \in \{y\}$.

Comment: What is the definition of $\{y\}$?

Comment: A singleton of the element y.

Comment: Could you write down the formal definition of $\{y\}$? It could be helpful to find a proof.

Comment: Let $S$ be a set, then $y \in S \leftrightarrow \{y\} \subset S$. This definition makes use of the equivalence I wish to prove, as you can see here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Singleton_of_Element_is_Subset

Comment: That is not a definition, it's a proposition.

Comment: $y \in \{ y \}$. Then use [axioms for equality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms)

Comment: Thank you, Mr Allegranza. Hence, the existence assumption is $y \in \{y\}$ (which is a tautology) and, as such, can be assumed per se. Since $x=y$, we apply substitution to conclude $x \in \{y\}$. If my reasoning is correct, then the complete uniqueness assumption would look like this: $\exists y [ y \in \{ y \} \land \forall z [z \in \{y\} \rightarrow z = y] ]$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider [$\mathsf {ZFC}$](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory/ZF.html); using Pairing axiom we prove that, for every $x,y$, the set $\{ x,y \}$ exists.

From this, with $x=y$, we have that also $\{ y \}$ exists and that $y \in \{ y \}$

Now, we have to use first-order [substitution axioms for equality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms):

> $y=x \to (y \in \{ y \} \to x \in \{ y \})$.

For the other part, by Pairing we have that $y$ is the unique element of $\{ y \}$. Thus, if $x \in \{ y \}$, then $x=y$.

Comment: My original idea, which I'm unsure if it's correct, was that it would be possiblie to prove $x \in \{y\} \leftrightarrow x = y$ without using ZFC. I thought it would suffice to assume the uniqueness of the element in $\{y\}$, therefore $\exists k [ k \in \{ y \} \land \forall z [z \in \{y\} \rightarrow z = k ]$, and use the existence part to prove $x = y \rightarrow x \in \{y\}$ and, as you stated, the uniqueness part to prove $x \in \{y\} \rightarrow x = y$. However, I can't see how to go on from there, since $x \in \{y\} \leftrightarrow x = y$ would have to hold true for every $k$.

Comment: @TylerD007 - the issue is that, outside set theory, $\{ y \}$ is a term, like e.g $f(y)$ and $\in$ is a binary predicate, like $I(x,y)$. Thus, in "pure" logic, $x \in \{ y \}$ is simply $I(x, f(y))$. Without axioms for them, how to prove that $x=y$ ?

Comment: To prove $x = y \rightarrow x \in \{y\}$, we would need to assume the existence of $y \in \{ y \}$. Since $y \in \{ y \}$ is logically equivalent to $\{ y \} \subseteq \{ y \}$, then I thought it would be a tautology and, in such condition, an universal assumption. Another way would be to consider the function $f : X \rightarrow \{ X \}$ and then proceed to prove $x = y \rightarrow \{x\} \subseteq \{y\}$, assuming $f(x) = \{x\}$ and $f(y) = \{y\}$. Of course, considerations about Cantor's Theorem would come up in mind.

Comment: As for $x \in \{y\} \rightarrow x = y$, it suffices to assume the uniqueness of x considering $\forall z[z \in \{y\} \rightarrow z = y]$. In conclusion, my point is: is it a coincidence that $y \in \{ y \}$ (existence) is used to prove the first half of the statement and $\forall z[z \in \{y\} \rightarrow z = y]$ (uniqueness) the second one?