# How to prove if $x$ is in a singleton set, say $S = \{ b \}$, then $x = b$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, definition

The motivation is for a linear algebra problem, but I think it it perfectly reasonable to exclude the linear algebra portion since this seems to be a large problem on it's own.

Suppose we have a singleton set (a set containing one element), $S = \{ b\}$. Suppose $x \in S$. How can we show that $x = b$?

I don't see anything in ZFT that can help. Is it so trivial that we can just say that is the definition of a singleton set?

Comment: By def of set-builder opeartor: $x \in S \text { iff } x=b$.

Comment: A more formal way is: from [Pairs Axiom](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory/ZF.html) we have that $\{ a,b \}$ exists for every sets $a,b$ and with it we prove that $x \in \{ a,b \} \text { iff } (x=a \lor x=b)$. The singleton is defined as follows: $\{ a \} = \{ a,a \}$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA yours is very nice, but an alternative might just be proof by contradiction: If x is not b, the cardinality is 2 or higher...

Comment: @anon - correct; see the answer below.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3651594/proof-of-x-y-leftrightarrow-x-in-y)

Comment: It’s not complicated. $(\forall y \in S)\,y = b$; but $x\in S$, so $x = b$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If possible, let $x\neq b$.

It is given that $S=\{b\}$. So, $b\in S$. Also, it is given that $x\in S$. So, both $x$ and $b$ are in $S$.

Now, because of [Axiom Of Pairing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_pairing), there is a set $S^\prime =\{x,b\}$. But, then the elements of $S$ and $S^\prime$ are same. So, by [Axiom Of Extensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality), $S=S^\prime$ hence giving $S=\{x,b\}$. This is a contradiction to $S=\{b\}$.

As Somos pointed out, one may still ask, why $\{x,b\}\neq \{b\}$. To show that, we can use the Extensionality Axiom once again to prove that if $A=\{x,b\}$ and $A^\prime=\{b\}$, then $A\neq A^\prime$ since $x\in A$ but $x\notin A^\prime$.

Comment: +1 to your answer - this is the analysis that I was going to use, and I do consider it valid.  However, I am ignorant of the formality of Set Theory, so it is plausible (in my mind) that your analysis constitutes circular reasoning.  That is, it is unclear to me, whether in formal Set Theory, you are permitted to reason as you did.

Comment: @user2661923 I understand your point. It's not circular. I'll edit it to make it more formal. Wait a moment.

Comment: @user2661923 please check the edit.

Comment: I am not qualified to have an opinion here.  It seems right, but, in my opinion, it would take an expert in Set Theory, to check the validity.

Comment: I don't see the contraction in $\,\{x,b\}=\{b\}\,$ from your argument. Of course, if $\,x\ne b\,$ then this is false, but you have not proven that yet. What am I missing?

Comment: @Somos doesn't extensionality axiom say that $A\neq A^\prime$ where $A=\{x,b\}$ and $A^\prime =\{b\}$ since $x\in A$ but $x\notin A^\prime$?

Comment: If that is your argument, than please include that in your answer.